# Combining multiple const = in an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

How can I combine in an array the data from `const =` `menuGallery`, `menuCompany` and `menuTour` to all be called within `menuData` (see code below) so that my `li` should display the `graphQl` data from all three in `const = menuData`

```
render() {
  const menuGallery = get(this.props, 'data.allContentfulImageGallery.edges')
  const menuCompany = get(this.props, 'data.allContentfulCompanyPage.edges')
  const menuTour = get(this.props, 'data.allContentfulTourPage.edges')
  const menuData = [{menuGallery},{menuCompany},{menuTour}]

  return(
    {menuData.map(({ node: page })=> (
      <li className={slug === page.slug ? "selected" : ""} key={page.id}><a href={`/${page.slug}`}>{page.title}</a></li>
  ))}
```

if I change the current `const menuData` to be const `menuData = menuGallery` it will show the data from the `allContentfulImageGallery` but when combining multiples they don't map the data.

the `graphQl` query

```
export const menuQuery = graphql`
query menuQuery($slug: String!) {
    allContentfulCompanyPage(sort: {fields: [menuOrder], order: ASC}) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          title
          slug
        }
      }
    }
    allContentfulTourPage(sort: {fields: [menuOrder], order: ASC}) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          title
          slug
        }
      }
    }
    allContentfulImageGallery(sort: {fields: [menuOrder], order: ASC}) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          title
          slug
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Each works and is mapped individually but I have multiple content types that make up the App pages and want to list them together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to combine three arrays into a single long one.

```
const menuData = [...menuGallery, ...menuCompany, ...menuTour]
```

Comment: Stellar! Thanks - are you able to help me understand what purpose the `...` have? I'll accept this as the answer once it allows.

Comment: Glad to help! Spread is a great ES6 feature for both arrays and objects-- just remember, that it is doing shallow-copies, so it can't be used as a deep-cloning utility.  Happy coding!